# Value Error: Could not convert string to float but no string in txt files

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I just started learning how to use pyplot and csv and the likes. When I tried to take a notepad file and sort it, I get thrown a value error. [This is the text file](https://github.com/joshbarbee/Reddit-bot/blob/master/Browns%20records). I am given the error on line 3 of this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x, y = np.loadtxt("kre.txt", delimiter=",", unpack=True)
plt.scatter(x,y,label = "Bar", color ="r")
plt.xlabel("Years")
plt.ylabel("Wins")
plt.title("Distribution of Browns wins per year")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I've looked around and found other people having this problem, but couldn't find a solution, or at least one I understood. The error message is:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python scripts\pi.py", line 3, in <module>
    x, y = np.loadtxt("kre.txt", delimiter=",", unpack=True)
  File "C:\Users\Josh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1024, in loadtxt
    items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
  File "C:\Users\Josh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1024, in <listcomp>
    items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
  File "C:\Users\Josh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 725, in floatconv
    return float(x)
```

It's fixed for some reason by creating a new file. I have no idea why

Comment: If you use np.genfromtxt, you could specify dtype=None, which will tell genfromtxt to intelligently guess the dtype of each column. Most conveniently, it relieves you of the burder of specifying the number of bytes required for the string column. (Omitting the number of bytes, by specifying e.g. np.str, does not not work.)

Comment: I have a feeling that there might be a newline at the end of the file giving you a blank line (github is showing 70 lines but 69 sloc) but not sure.

Comment: @roganjosh That was just github being weird when I uploaded the files.

Comment: @v0rtex so if you open the file in a text editor, there definitely isn't a blank line right at the bottom?

Comment: @roganjosh There is no extra line right at the bottom. I've opened it in notepad, and even wordpad mobile of all things, and non showed an extra line at the bottom.

Comment: I've just copy/pasted the file contents locally and tried. I cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: @roganjosh I eventually got it to work, fortunately, by copy & pasting it into a new file. I think it may have been due to a duplicate file name somewhere causing the error.

Comment: You'll get this if you have a blank line somewhere in you file. Some editors add this line once you save the file.